# how to create parallel threads in same class member using boost in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, parallel-processing

I want to create two parallel threads using `boost`. One thread to add data to request queue and other thread to monitor the data from the response queue.

I have created a thread for the request queue as follows.

In a member function `start_monitoring()`, I create a thread to handle request.

```
m_ReqThrd = new boost::thread((boost::bind(&t::HandleRequest, this)));
m_ReqThrd ->join();
```

After this if I try to create another thread in the same member function, it does not get created until the first thread (Request thread) exits.

```
m_RespThrd = new boost::thread((boost::bind(&t::HandleResponse, this)));
m_RespThrd ->join();
```

I want to monitor both response and request queue in parallel threads. So how can I create parallel threads inside same member function of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join` is a blocking call - it waits for the thread to finish, so calling it *immediately* after creating the thread is usually pointless - you could have called the function the newly created thread will execute yourself.

Generally you only want to `join` as the program's finished its work and is shutting down.  You should give some thought to how you'll know when to start shutting down, e.g.:

- never - just run until something external kills your process
- when some specific input's received
- when a certain number of events have happened
- when some queue is empty
- when some deadline's expired
- etc.